# Angular 6 multiple routing outlets with child routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading, ng-modules

I have app module which imports two child modules: `PreparationModule` and `GameModule`. In root routing for `AppModule` i have 'preparation' endpoint which lazy loads `PreparationModule`. `AppComponent`'s (bootstrap component for `AppModule`) html file contains only root router outlet. `PreparationModule` has its own child routing with two child routes and named router outlet for those routes in PreparationComponent.

What i wanna achieve is that on path '/preparation' the `PreparationComponent` will be displayed in `AppComponent` router outlet. Then the child routes from `PreparationModule` will be lazy loaded and displayed in named router outlet in `PreparationComponent` on for instance path '/preparation/intro'. On path '/play' i wanna load `GameComponent` from `GameModule` into `AppComponents` router outlet. `GameModule` doesn't have its own routing specified for now.

What am i doing wrong here? I guess i explained it in complicated way, but maybe code will tell you more. There's nothing relevant inside `app.component.ts` and `preparation.component.ts` (just the class declaration) so i skipped them.

EDIT

The error i'm gettings is: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function`

> app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRouting,
    SharedModule,
    GameModule,
    PreparationModule
  ],
  declarations: [
   AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

> app.component.html

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

> app.routing.ts

```
// These goes inside main <router-outlet></router-outlet> in 
// AppComponent
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'preparation',
    component: PreparationComponent,
    loadChildren: './preparation/preparation.module#PreparationModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'play',
    component: GameComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/preparation',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

> preparation.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[
    PreparationRouting,
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports:[
    PreparationComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    IntroComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  declarations:[
    PreparationComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    IntroComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ]
})
export class PreparationModule {
}
```

> preparation.component.html

```
<div id="main-container" fxFlex="80" fxFlex.xs="94" fxFlexOffset="10" fxFlexOffset.xs="3"
     fxLayout="column" fxFlexAlign="center">

  <div fxFlex="4"></div>
  <div fxFlex="92" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <div fxFlex.gt-md="45" fxFlex.md="60" fxFlex.sm="85" fxFlex.xs="100">
      <router-outlet name="preparation"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
  <app-footer fxFlex="4"></app-footer>
</div>
```

> preparation.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'intro',
    component: IntroComponent,
    outlet: 'preparation'
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    outlet: 'preparation'
  }
];

export const PreparationRouting = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```